# dd on macOS: ISO -> USB creates only Apple_partition_map

Tags: command-line, usb, dd, iso, macos

I tried to make bootable linux USB drive with SDHC 8Gb flash card on my MacBook with `dd command` according to [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md)

Also I googled a lot and found out that was the same [issue in the past](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288713/ddcommand-iso-to-usb-changes-partition-table-to-apm) and no solution.

So, step by step what was done:

1. mount flash and check it with `diskutil list` command
   I got something like this:

```
    /dev/disk2 (external, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk2
       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
       2:       Microsoft Basic Data UNTITLED                7.8 GB     disk2s2
```

2. then I unmount partitions `/dev/disk2s1` and `/dev/disk2s2` to leave only the physical device `/dev/disk2` mounted, because otherwise I'll get "resource busy" alert
3. I start dd command like:

```
sudo dd if={path to my file, something like ./linux_dist.iso} of=/dev/disk2 bs=10m
```

I used `of=/dev/rdisk2` as well, no luck

4. Waiting for the completion

```
485+1 records in
485+1 records out
2545156096 bytes transferred in 2005.199388 secs (1269278 bytes/sec)
```

5.run `diskutil list` again:

```
    /dev/disk2 (external, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk2
       1:        Apple_partition_map                         4.1 KB     disk2s1
       2:                  Apple_HFS                         4.1 MB     disk2s2
```

So, no matter how and what I tried I got this constant result.
Any thought what am I doing wrong ?

PS: I tried ubuntu-mate.iso and antiX.iso

Comment: I have the exact same issue and the exact same question. Did you ever figure this out? Any answers?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: Darnit. its very frazzling to me.